# angular 4 - call child component function from parent component html

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need to call child component function from parent component html.

something like this:

child component:

```
export class childComponent {
  private value: boolean;

  @input()
  setValue(inputVal){
    this.value = inputVal;
  }
}
```

parent component:

```
<childComponent  [setValue] = "true"></childComponent>
```

Any ideas how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with view child

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'child-cmp',
      template: '<p>child</p>'
    })
    class ChildCmp {
      doSomething() {}
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'some-cmp',
      template: '<child-cmp></child-cmp>',
      directives: [ChildCmp]
    })
    class SomeCmp {
      @ViewChild(ChildCmp) child:ChildCmp;
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        // child is set
        this.child.doSomething();
      }
    }
```

or you can also do with string

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
  doSomething() {}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: '<child-cmp #child></child-cmp>',
  directives: [ChildCmp]
})
class SomeCmp {
  @ViewChild('child') child:ChildCmp;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // child is set
    this.child.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Looking for up voting my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a method using @input. You can do this by using @ViewChild

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class childComponent {
   value : anyl
   setValue(inputVal){
     this.value = inputVal;
  }
}
```

and then in parent component

```
class SomeCmp {
  @ViewChild(ChildCmp) child:ChildCmp;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child.setValue(yourval);
  }
}
```

Comment: Intha shay yar Anwerum accept panna mattan ninaikren :)

Comment: how do you know tamil ?

Comment: naan tamil than.